# Quantum measurement and exchange interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements, exchange-interaction

If we consider a two-electron system, the operators (say, momentum or spin) for the first and the second electron are commuting, and so, these values may be considered measurable together. Moreover, the system is considered to transit to a state which is an eigenfunction of the measured value operator. However, there is also inevitably an exchange coupling between these electrons. So how does it affect the measurement? Say, if we measure the momentum of the first eletron, but don't distrub the second electron, what is the state of the system after the measurement?